# New Android Toolbar: How to hide the overflow menu icon?

Tags: android, icons, android-toolbar, overflow-menu

I just created an app including the new Android toolbar. My problem is: How would I hide this overflow menu icon/button: http://prntscr.com/62mmus ?
I already tried this, but it's not working:

```
        Toolbar mToolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        mToolbar.hideOverflowMenu();
```

Comment: "How would I hide this overflow menu icon/button" -- don't put any action items in the action bar. Remove your `onCreateOptionsMenu()` and `onOptionsItemSelected()` methods, along with the `menu` resource(s) that they use. Then, the overflow should never show up.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Just use:

```
@Override
public boolean onPrepareOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        return false;
}
```

Comment: Simply Perfect. Thanks.

Comment: This also prevents the Up (Back) button from reacting to its click event.

Comment: This disables the hamburger actions if there is any navigation drawer. Just don't implement onCreateOptionsMenu() method and Overflow menu won't show up.

Comment: How do you call 'return' on a method/function that doesn't return anything?

Answer (score 3):

This is how I did it.

This is my original menu_main.xml file under the menu folder:

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" tools:context=".MainActivity">
    <item android:id="@+id/action_settings" android:title="@string/action_settings"
        android:orderInCategory="100" app:showAsAction="never" />
</menu>
```

Delete the item:

```
    <item android:id="@+id/action_settings" android:title="@string/action_settings"
        android:orderInCategory="100" app:showAsAction="never" />
```

Go to your main activity and comment out the following if (id == R.id.action_settings) :

```
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();

    //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
   // if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
   //     return true;
   // }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
```

Run your app - the overflow menu icon is gone.

Answer (score 2):

what worked for me was:
add the  following: 
android:visible="false" to the menu item in the menu file (global.xml) in the menu folder.

ex:

```
 <item
    android:id="@+id/action_settings"
    android:orderInCategory="100"
    android:showAsAction="never"
    android:title="@string/action_settings"
    android:visible="false"

    />
```

Answer (score 1):

Just return false when calling the method **onCreateOptionsMenu**

Ex:

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    if (!showToolbarMenu)
        return false;
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main_activity, menu);
    return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
}
```

Comment: If you return false just in the beginning of `onCreateOptionsMenu()`, will you add items there?

Answer (score 0):

Use the command 
`invalidateOptionsMenu();`

And your problems will be solved.

Comment: Please consider adding additional details as to why this is the correct answer.

Comment: This works if neither the current fragment nor activity override onCreateOptionsMenu, as it forces the system to try to inflate the menu again. Not finding any menu to show, it will then hide the icon.

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me, I just deleted the line getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main_activity, menu);

Answer (score 0):

Don't implement the `onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu)` method. If you do anyway ,don't use this method `getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);` as this line in the  `onCreateOptionsMenu` method inflates the overflow button with the menus declared in resource `R.menu.main`.